# How to name new projects without confusing anyone

Tags: software-development, software

I recently transitioned into a sort of engineer position where I am the most newest member of my team. For the past month since I started, I've been working on other people's projects and nothing came up.

This last week, I was assigned some new projects that I would be primarily working on alone.  When I tried to create a repository name using only my name, I noticed the name was already taken and even the abbreviation of my first and last. I went ahead and appended a "1" and went on with my work. I spent all week working on my code - following the standards (all data objects must be the name of the repository to easily search for who did what) and finally made a large push. This was somehow noticed and it upset a few people and they told me to choose another name as it was already taken. No matter how I argued, they kept citing proper software naming techniques that I wasn't following.

I'm still thinking of how people come up with how to name projects/code and I would like to know any techniques people use when coming up with names?

Comment: VTC - this is either a Software development question (not applicable) or it is a question around a companies internal naming conventions - which we cannot assist with.

Comment: Projects are often given random codenames but this does seem like an internal company problem. Ask them what they want. Use that.

Comment: "When I tried to create a repository name **using only my name**, I noticed the name was already taken and even **the abbreviation of my first and last**." Do you mean you named the repository not after the project's name but literally your own name? Say your name is Minda Smith, the repository name now is ms1?

Comment: You should have asked your colleagues for guidance. I'm not sure what mindset would lead to thinking that (following MisterMiyagi's example), if there already is a project `ms`, that it would make sense and be OK to create something called `ms1`. Of course that is confusing. It's similar to creating documents called "important document.docx", "important document (1).docx", "important document (final version).docx" and "important document (really final version).docx"...

Comment: Ask those who have an opinion to agree on one and just use that.

Comment: "This was somehow noticed and it upset a few people and they told me to choose another name as it was already taken. No matter how I argued, they kept citing proper software naming techniques that I wasn't following." Why did you argue? As the newest member, what could you possibly gain from arguing over such a non-issue? These people are not your parents. If you continue to argue every little bit of feedback they give you, they'll just fire you. In any case, see the book "Code Complete" by Steve McConnell. But next time, as the newest member, just defer to the judgement of your colleagues.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot tell you how to name your projects, that is up to you and your companies guidelines.

*However*, working in a company is a collaboration. You don't work alone. If you notice the obvious name for the project is already taken, you *talk* to people. You ask around, why it's already taken? Maybe someone else started it? Maybe it is old and you are building the replacement? Maybe you misunderstood what you should build? Maybe someone can come up with a better name? You don't just slap a random digit on it and call it a day.

The same goes for your push. Don't make lots and lots of changes and only talk about them with people in the end. That means lots of time wasted, when you did something "wrong". I set "wrong" in quotation marks because it might not be your fault. You may not have had that piece of information or maybe your boss just changed their mind. But the output is nevertheless wrong and needs to be corrected. And the sooner it is corrected, the less you are working in the wrong direction. So *talk* to people. Push your changes in small increments and ask if that is what is required. Whether it is informal by asking a colleague next to you, or formal through required code reviews. But *communicate* with colleagues to make sure you produce the best outcome possible.

This is not about naming something. Maybe the name was good. Maybe not. Maybe the next company wants it named differently. It is about communicating your decisions often and early, so that when they do not fit the requirements, it's easy to change it and easy to just say "oh yeah sure, no problem" and move on with a better product, instead of looking at your work going "oh no, now I have to change it all".